# How to calculate all action running time in asp.net mvc5 with custom action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, stopwatch, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I want to log  execution time of almost all actions in asp.net mvc5 but basically doing this with below code is the correct way or it makes the project very slow ? Any suggestion?

```
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        sw.Start();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        float f = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: this looks ok to me, it definitely will not make your code slower. you might have a concurency problem though. I am not sure that a separate filter instance is created for each request. If not you could have incorrect measurements once there are multiple requests. you might need to store the timings in a dictionary or on the context itself to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: @Jim Thanks a lot for your suggesstion the timings should be in dictionary to avaoid concurrency problem.

Comment: I think it's used per request, but what happens when a exception occurs?

Comment: @Legends I have global exception filter too.I am logging it . It redirects to error page  and the customer calls :)

Comment: I mean, will the exception be passed back through the OnActionExecuted, otherwise the the sw will run until it's disposed.

Comment: @Legends you are right.It also never hits the real method.It is a possible problem.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would perhaps store the timing in a appropriately scoped location, perhaps on the request.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Items["timer"] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

that way you avoid using a cumbersome dictionary, and your timer is on a `per request` basis.

You can then cast the value in `OnActionExecuted`

```
        var sw = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["timer"] as Stopwatch;
        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds...
```